# Why would a space be forbidden at a specific location of a connection string and not at other locations?

Tags: c#, mariadb, connection-string, ado

A connection is successfully set with a connection string for MariaDB using the [ODBC connector (3.0.9)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/):

```
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection()) {
    connection.ConnectionString =
        "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver};" +
        "SERVER = localhost; PORT = 3306;" +
        "DATABASE = mybase;" +
        "USER = id; PASSWORD = password";
    // ...
}
```

This code works. Adding a space before "=" sign for the DRIVER key/value pair, like this:

```
"DRIVER ={MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver};"
```

... breaks the program and throws a `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException`:

`ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Adding a space after the "=" sign is accepted, as well as everywhere for other key/value pairs in the string.

Can someone explain why it isn't allowed to add a white between "DRIVER" and "="?

Comment: Although the answer to this may be interesting, why do you care? Technique A doesn't work, Technique B does. Why do you care **why** Technique A doesn't work when you can just use Technique B?

Comment: @mjwills: The reason is by understanding a problem one can potentially be aware of other problems in the same category.